# Upgrading to Debian 7: Postfix Auth fails

Tags: debian, postfix, ldap, sasl, cyrus

I'm upgrading various Debian 6 servers to Debian 7. There are a few minor issues, but this one is a show stopper.

On Debian, Postfix runs in a chrooted environment. That environment is setup correctly (it was working perfectly on Debian6).

I only use software from the stable releases from the debian repository

The relevant (parts of the) configs (anonymised):

in /etc/default/saslauthd:

---

```
START=yes
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="ldap"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
PARAMS=" -m /var/spool/postfix/run/saslauthd -O /etc/saslauthd.conf"
OPTIONS=" -m /var/spool/postfix/run/saslauthd -O /etc/saslauthd.conf"
PIDFILE="/var/spool/postfix/run/saslauthd/saslauthd.pid"
```

### in /etc/saslauthd.conf:

```
# With multiple servers, separate URIs with a space
ldap_servers: ldaps://my.ldap.server

# Don't use SASL to connect to LDAP!! (Use SSL)
#ldap_version: 3
ldap_use_sasl: no
ldap_bind_dn: uid=courier,ou=roles,dc=mydomain,dc=tld

#watch out for trailing whitespace after the pasword!
ldap_bind_pw: #######
ldap_timeout: 10
ldap_time_limit: 10

ldap_scope: sub 
ldap_search_base: ou=people,dc=mydomain,dc=tld
ldap_auth_method: bind
ldap_filter: (mail=%u)
#ldap_filter: (mail=%u@%r)

ldap_debug: 1
ldap_verbose: off 
ldap_referrals: yes 

# Settings below are needed for ldaps URIs
ldap_ssl: yes 
ldap_start_tls: no
ldap_tls_cacert_file: /etc/ssl/certs/allcacerts.pem
ldap_tls_cert: /etc/ssl/certs/myserver.mydomain.tld.crt
ldap_tls_key: /etc/ssl/private/myserver.mydomain.tld.key
```

### in /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf:

```
#global parameters
log_level: 5
# WARNING !!! POSTFIX runs in a chrooted jail!!
# Need to adjust paths to get the socket available!
# adjust this in /etc/defaults/saslauthd
# eg: PARAMS=/var/spool/postfix/run/saslauthd/
# real saslauthd_path: /var/spool/postfix/run/saslauthd/mux
pwcheck_method: saslauthd 
saslauthd_path: /run/saslauthd/mux
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
auxprop_plugin: ldapdb
#allow_plaintext: true
#the database used is /var/spool/postfix/etc/sasldb2
```

### in /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
#sasl configuration
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtpd_sasl_path= smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
#broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

# TLS configuration
smtpd_use_tls = yes 
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1 
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes 
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/myserver.mydomain.tld.key
#smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/myserver.mydomain.tld.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file  = /etc/ssl/certs/myserver.mydomain.tld.pem
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
# CAfile is read BEFORE entering chroot jail
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/allcacerts.pem
# CApath is used withIN chroot jail
#smtpd_tls_CApath = /usr/share/ssl/certs/
```

Cyrus SASL has it's socket in `/var/spool/postfix/run/saslauthd/mux`

I test with:

`testsaslauthd -s smtpd -f /var/spool/postfix/run/saslauthd/mux -u USER@REALM.TLD -p PASSWD`

Gives: `0: OK "Success."`

FYI: With incorrect credentials is does fail :)

With these results my conclusion is that sasl is working correctly.

### When I use 'swaks' to test ESMTP Auth:

`swaks -s myserver.mydomain.tld -p 25 -ehlo myclient.mydomain.tld -au USER@REALM.TLD -ap PASSWD -t sender@mydomain.tld -f recipient@anotherdomain.tld`

```
=== Trying myserver.mydomain.tld:25...
=== Connected to myserver.mydomain.tld.
<-  220 ***********************
 -> EHLO myclient.mydomain.tld
<-  250-myserver.mydomain.tld
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 15360000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-XXXXXXXA
<-  250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250 DSN
 -> AUTH LOGIN
<-  334 VXNlcmgfhgWU6
 -> bWFyY2hgh28ubmw=
<-  334 UGFzfghdfmQ6
 -> bWFyUzYdfghgfhg==
<** 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: no mechanism available
 -> AUTH PLAIN AG1hcmdfhgdfgd1hclM2NW9ndCo=
<** 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: no mechanism available
*** No authentication type succeeded
 -> QUIT
<-  221 2.0.0 Bye
=== Connection closed with remote host.
```

### And in the logs:

```
postfix/smtpd[5646]:auxpropfunc error invalid parameter supplied
postfix/smtpd[5646]:_sasl_plugin_load failed on sasl_auxprop_plug_init for plugin: ldapdb
postfix/smtpd[5646]:anonuserfunc error -7
postfix/smtpd[5646]:_sasl_plugin_load failed on sasl_canonuser_init for plugin: ldapdb 
postfix/smtpd[5646]:warning: unknown[192.168.114.69 : SASL LOGIN authentication failed: no mechanism available 
postfix/smtpd[5646]:warning: unknown[192.168.114.69 : SASL PLAIN authentication failed: no mechanism available
```

(IP is of the client machine)

The postfix user is a member of the sasl group.

I know Debian changed the library directory structure by inserting a triplet, to make it multi-arch capable.

What used to be: `/usr/lib/sasl2`
is now: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2` (for x86 64bits systems)

I did copy the sasl2 directory to various places to make the libraries available, but it didn't change a thing.

Anyone?

Marcel

Answer (score 2):

I Solved it!

It took a lot of debugging, but everything works again with the following settings:

### In /etc/postfix/smtpd.conf:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
saslauthd_path: /run/saslauthd/mux
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
# DO NOT SPECIFY THE AUX_PROP PLUGIN!!
#auxprop_plugin: ldapdb
```

### In /etc/saslauthd.conf:

```
...
ldap_auth_method: bind
#ldap_filter: (mail=%u)
ldap_filter: (mail=%u@%r)
...
```

Originally I had this filter, but because I saw in the LDAP log loginattempts for  `user@domain.tld@`, I had changed the filter (see my original post).

## !! All I needed was to comment out the auxprop_plugin setting !!

Please note, however, that in my sasl setup I **ONLY** use the ldap backend.

Marcel

Comment: Thanks man, it helped after several hours of debugging and reading. Please accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> warning: localhost[127.0.0.1]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: no mechanism available

I was having the same problem, but I use mysql. After commenting out this line: `#auxprop_plugin`, all works fine!

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login cram-md5 digest-md5
allow_plaintext: true
#auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: postfix
sql_passwd: pass
sql_database: postfix
loglevel: 0
sql_select: select password from mailbox where username = '%u@%r'
```